# Incorrect behavior when sending email with use a block inside a template

Tags: magento2, blocks, template, email

When developing the module I encountered the following problem: 
inside the my controller (`class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`) there is a method that calls a method to send email `send()` (inside class `EmailSenderResultsSync extends AbstractHelper`).

E-mail is sent and works well until the template file (`view/frontend/email/sync-report/index.html`) contains only html code, for example:

`<h1>Title</h1>`

But when I try to insert a block in the template as follows:

`{{block class='Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template' area='frontend' template='<vendor>_<module>::email/sync-report/test.phtml' }}`

an email is sent (along with the contents of the block) only 1 time. The next time you contact the controller  (`class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`), it does not work. The controller does not perform any actions at all.

There is no information in the logs.

I hope for help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot **call block** like this in **email template**.

Here You have allowed customization for magento 2:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html